# Break a jQuery Datepicker Altfield into 2 elements

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to replace the default booking.com affiliate calendar by a clean jQuery instance. Replicating (and improving) the initial UI / UX is quite straightforward. I'm stuck when it comes to matching the parameters needed by booking.com.

As many others posted here, I need my friendly date for visitors AND another output that will be passed on to booking.com. I've used AltField, no probs here. The complexity (for me) is that booking requires "year month" and "day" as 2 separate parameters.
I tried setting up multiple altfields, I tried parsing/substringing my altfield, but all in vain.

Could you please give me some directions ?

```
$(".full_date").datepicker({
showOn: 'button',
buttonText: 'Here',
dateFormat: 'D, dd M yy',
altFormat: "yy-mm_dd",
altField: "checkin_year_month",
onClose: function (dateText, picker) {
    dateArr = dateText.split('_');
    full_date.siblings('.checkin_year_month').val(dateArr[0]);
    full_date.siblings('.checkin_day').val(dateArr[1]);
}
});
```

I've also setup a [jsFiddle if that helps](http://jsfiddle.net/toutgreg/YynL5/) !

Thanks
Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you have't solved this yet.

your problem is on this line :

```
dateArr = dateText.split('_');
```

What would be better is this :

```
var dateObject = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
```

This will return you a Date object that you can work with :

```
dateObject.getMonth()
```

Here is a [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/GwFWk/)

Comment: Of course ! When I look at your code it all makes sense. Thanks rusln.

Comment: One last thing, what would be the correct way to output "year_month" (2 values combined into 1 field) in one text field (not span) and "day" into a second one ?

Comment: You already had that part right, but i've updated the fiddle with an example.

Comment: So that covers the "year_month" part PERFECTLY. Exactly what I needed.  I've been struggling with the second altfield with a different altFromat. How would you suggest I go about a second field for "day" ?